# Size of directories only not files

Tags: command-line, 18.04, files, filesystem

This has probably been answered elsewhere but can't seem to find it and apologies for the duplicate/basic question.

I want to simply be able to display the file size of folders in a directory.

Running `du -h` lists all the folders but it also includes files in the directory. I'd prefer it to display similar to the below...

`Documents  Size mb
 Temp       Size mb
 Pictures   Size mb
 Videos     Size mb
Total size`

Bonus if i could get the total at the end included. Is the possible through a simple command?

Thanks

Comment: `du -h -c -d0 Downloads/*/` lists the size of all directories in `Downloads` also includes total.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used `du -shc *` which worked perfectly with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
du -sh *
```

The s option there means "summarize", to display only a total for each argument, and the * means you will get that for each directory (and file) where you stand.

Comment: Perfect!! I added `du -shc *` and worked exactly as i hoped. Thank you!